# Insert a specific part of text into mysql with php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am trying insert some information into mysql db. One of the elements is a textarea which I filled with javascript code below. So it contains an html content. When I try to insert into db, it is inserted with html syntax (with  tags and  etc.). I want to insert only specific part of that content.

```
$('#checkoutButton').click(function(){  


        var content2 = $('#checkout').html();

        $('#checkoutText').val(content2);

});
```

For instance, this is the content and I want to insert only "2 Cappuccino" and "2 Fiesta" part. What should I do?

```
<h3 align="centre">Order List</h3>
<p class="items"><span>2 Cappuccino</span><span class="extra">asahsajd</span></p><p   class="items">  <span>2 Adet Fiesta</span><span class="extra">abvsvss </span></p>
```

Comment: Why is it you are trying to parse html rather than have a form in the first place that you can post the separate items and then insert them into the DB?

Comment: how can I reach separated items of a form? What is your advice?

Answer (score 0):

You should be submitting this data via a form.

```
<form action='/url-to-send-data'>
    <input type='text' name='input1'>
    <input type='text' name='input2'>
    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can access what data is going into the html you gave as an example you need to wrap inputs in a form which can make it easier to post the data to php:

```
<h3 align="centre">Order List</h3>
<form method="post">
    <div class="items">
        <input type="text" name="item[]" value="2 Cappuccino" />
        <input type="text" name="extras[]" class="extra" value="asahsajd"/>
    </div>

    <div class="items">
        <input type="text" name="item[]" value="2 Adet Fiesta"/>
        <input type="text" name="extras[]" class="extra" value="abvsvss"/>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

You can change their values or append items to the form. Upon posting you can access them as arrays using the `$_POST` variable in PHP:

```
<?php
    var_dump($_POST['item']);
?>
```

Comment: but the list is dynamic, I dont know how many rows it contains until button clicked.

Comment: Cant you use the button click to append a new item or append appropriate items to the form using Jquery?